# How to call Objective C viewcontroller in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I found a `ViewController` SDK using objective C. I want to use it swift but fail to call.

Can you suggest me any idea for using it?

I want to create a storyboard and set the custom class in `ViewControllerObjectiveC`, but still fail to open the `viewcontroller`.

```
let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerObjectiveC") as! ViewControllerObjectiveC
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
self.presentingViewController?.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: Try to change last two lines as => 


self.dismiss(animated: true) {
      self.presentingViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Answer (score 1):

In order to interact Obj-C code with Swift you will need to have a bridging header file. The name of the bridging header MUST be like `<YourProject>-Bridging-Header.h`. While you can create it manually there is an option which the Xcode creates it yourself. For the second option create a new file with .m extension. The Xcode will ask you to create a bridging header. Approve it.

Now import everything in this file you need to reach from Swift. In your case put the following inside your bridging header:

```
#import "ViewControllerObjectiveC.h"
```

Assuming your Obj-C file has the name ViewControllerObjectiveC.h. The code you shared should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Bridging Header is the way to solve your problem.

See this Apple Document:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift

**Step 1** 
Drag and drop your Objective-C files into the project after that you will see this message inside your Xcode project.

[See this popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6e1a.png)

Then click on Create Bridging header option. It will create one header file inside your project.

[Confirm Header File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93irg.png)

Now you just have to Import your Objective C File into created header file.

That's It.

Comment: @ebank dsb Can you please look into this answer and do let me know if you required more information. Thanks